# How to generate new instance of the method caller class dynamically Java Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have 2 java classes `(Child1.java and Child2.java)` which extends from a common class `(Parent.java)`. I have another common class `(Common.java)` which can be called from both Child classes. I am getting the caller class name from the `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` and crate the Class instance through `Java Reflection`. Then I am creating a new instance object from that class. Therefore the return type of the method is `Object`

Although I am returning an object at the moment, I need `commonMethod()` to be written in a such a way where the called class new instance should be returned dynamically.

```
public class Child1 extends Parent {

  public void method1()
  {
    new Common().commonMethod();
  }

}

public class Child2 extends Parent {

  public void method2()
  {
    new Common().commonMethod();
  }

}


public Object commonMethod() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
{
  String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();
  Class clazz = Class.forName(className);

  return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is almost certainly the wrong approach. Instead, why not have `commonMethod` take a parameter of type `Supplier<? extends Parent>`, and have its callers pass e.g. `Child1::new`?

Comment: Actually this needs to be done without getting a parameter. Although the code segment is written to explain the scenario, this is actually a automation page object related code segment where you do not send the caller for common approaches, but still you need to redirected to the caller page. I can get the called from the stack-trace. But I just need to return the actual caller class to be returned

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
public <T extends Object>T commonMethod() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, 
IllegalAccessException
{
  String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();
  Class clazz = Class.forName(className);

  return (T) clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
public Parent commonMethod() {
   // blah blah..
}
```

```java
    public class Child1 extends Parent {

        public void method1()
        {
            new Common() {
                @Override
                public Child1 commonMethod() {
                    return new Child1();
                }
            }.commonMethod();
        }

    }

    public class Child2 extends Parent {

        public void method2()
        {
            new Common() {
                @Override
                public Child2 commonMethod() {
                    return new Child2();
                }
            }.commonMethod();
        }
    }
```

Your structure is not good.
But I think there a reason. 
Good luck.